# Link spidev and can device

Tags: spi

My pi3 has 2 mcp25625 devices connected. The first is connected to `spidev0.0`, the second to `spidev1.2`. They both work correctly, after making an overlay (based on https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1804) and setting the right `/boot/config.txt` parameters:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=20000000,interrupt=5

dtoverlay=spi1-3cs,cs0_spidev=disabled,cs1_spidev=disabled
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can2,oscillator=20000000,interrupt=6
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835
```

This works, but sometimes the `can0` and `can1` devices are mixed up:

```
[    3.830843] mcp251x spi0.0 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    3.842469] mcp251x spi1.2 can1: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
```

Versus:

```
[    3.799918] mcp251x spi1.2 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    3.811296] mcp251x spi0.0 can1: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
```

I was thinking that I might be able to utilize `udev` for this, but as far as I know that requires an address for the can devices, which I don't seem to have. Both `/sys/class/net/can0/address` and `/sys/class/net/can1/address` are empty.

Is there a way to connect the correct spidev with the correct can name at all boots?

The `/sys/class/net/can{0,1}/uevent` might help, there are no `/dev/can{0,1}` files:

```
root@canpi:~# ls -al /dev/can{0,1}
ls: cannot access '/dev/can0': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/dev/can1': No such file or directory
root@canpi:~# cat /sys/class/net/can{0,1}/uevent
INTERFACE=can0
IFINDEX=3
INTERFACE=can1
IFINDEX=4
root@canpi:~#
```

The output of `udevadm info /sys/class/net/can0` is even more promising:

```
$ udevadm info /sys/class/net/can0
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f215080.spi/spi_master/spi1/spi1.2/net/can0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f215080.spi/spi_master/spi1/spi1.2/net/can0
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=mcp251x
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f215080.spi
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f215080_spi
E: IFINDEX=4
E: INTERFACE=can0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/can0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3889130
```

Comment: If the devices can be hotplugged, did you try using `udev monitor` to see if there is any information to hook into when they are added?  Presuming `canX` refers to `/dev` entries you could also check `udevadm -a -p /dev/whatever`.

Comment: They cannot be live plugged (as they are on a hat). There are no `/dev/can{0,1}` files on the pi. So I am afraid that the udev tools don't work. The `/sys/class/net/can{0,1}/uevent` files do exist and contain info. I'll add the output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching further, I decided to make my own `udev` rule in order to fix this:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/75-can.rules
SUBSYSTEM!="net", GOTO="my_can_end"
ACTION!="add", GOTO="my_can_end"

DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/net/can?", ATTR{id}="SPI0", ENV{SPI}="0", NAME="can0"
DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/soc/3f215080.spi/spi_master/spi1/spi1.2/net/can?", ATTR{id}="SPI1", ENV{SPI}="1", NAME="can1"

LABEL="my_can_end"
```

This makes sure that additions to the subsystem `net` are being parsed for matches on device path. As the device path contains the spi bus, the name can be set based on the bus.

```
pi@canpi:~ $ dmesg | grep can[0-1]
[    3.875577] mcp251x spi1.2 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    3.893817] mcp251x spi0.0 can1: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    3.915604] mcp251x spi1.2 rename3: renamed from can0
[    3.965174] mcp251x spi0.0 can0: renamed from can1
[    4.040393] mcp251x spi1.2 can1: renamed from rename3
[    7.859240] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
[    8.143414] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can1: link becomes ready
pi@canpi:~ $
```

And during other boots:

```
pi@canpi:~ $ dmesg | grep can[0-1]
[    3.825023] mcp251x spi0.0 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    3.836400] mcp251x spi1.2 can1: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    7.314775] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can1: link becomes ready
[    7.335641] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
pi@canpi:~ $
```

I also set the environment variable "`SPI`" to contain the SPI number:

```
$ udevadm info /sys/class/net/can0
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/net/can0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/net/can0
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=mcp251x
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f204000.spi
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f204000_spi
E: IFINDEX=3
E: INTERFACE=can0
E: SPI=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/can0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3831919
```