# CAN interfaces don't match physical setup

Tags: can-bus

Using the [seeed studio CAN hat](https://www.seeedstudio.com/CAN-BUS-FD-HAT-for-Raspberry-Pi-p-4742.html?queryID=94abfeefd7678a538c162847350f4663&objectID=4742&indexName=bazaar_retailer_products), occasionally the interfaces for CAN get flipped from what they are physically on the hat.

```
[    7.736082] mcp251xfd spi0.1 can0: MCP2518FD rev0.0 (-RX_INT -MAB_NO_WARN +CRC_REG +CRC_RX +CRC_TX +ECC -HD c:40.00MHz m:20.00MHz r:17.00MHz e:16.66MHz) successfully initialized.
[    7.746477] mcp251xfd spi0.0 can1: MCP2518FD rev0.0 (-RX_INT -MAB_NO_WARN +CRC_REG +CRC_RX +CRC_TX +ECC -HD c:40.00MHz m:20.00MHz r:17.00MHz e:16.66MHz) successfully initialized.
```

*Note* - spi0.1 can0 should be spi0.1 can1

When running on Raspbian 10 (buster), I could add the udev rule (obtained [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76370/link-spidev-and-can-device#new-answer?newreg=641cef33434f46a0b0c1e5dfa8ff53fc))

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/soc/*/spi0.0/net/can?", NAME="can0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/soc/*/spi0.1/net/can?", NAME="can1"
```

and would get the following output with `dmesg`

```
[    7.777292] mcp251xfd spi0.1 rename4: renamed from can0
[    7.835669] mcp251xfd spi0.0 can0: renamed from can1
[    7.885438] mcp251xfd spi0.1 can1: renamed from rename4
```

so that the CAN interfaces would match correctly with how they were physically set up on the HAT.

Now when running Rasbian 11 (bullseye), with the same rule, I get the following when running `journalctl | grep can`

```
Dec 04 12:42:49 hostname systemd-udevd[178]: can0: Failed to rename network interface 3 from 'can0' to 'can1': File exists
Dec 04 12:42:49 hostname systemd-udevd[178]: can0: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
Dec 04 12:42:49 hostname systemd-udevd[185]: can1: Failed to rename network interface 4 from 'can1' to 'can0': File exists
Dec 04 12:42:49 hostname systemd-udevd[185]: can1: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
```

Has anyone seen this behavior when switching to bullseye? Is there a better approach to doing this?